# error management service for my Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, exception

I am looking for error management service for my Ruby on Rails project, Can any one suggest the best tool with lower price.

I have 5 Rails projects.

I found one tool http://www.batbugger.io/ is free in beta version, Does have any idea about that. It looks fine.

Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: or run your own https://github.com/errbit/errbit

Answer (score 1):

I would go with https://github.com/errbit/errbit. Errbit use the same API as Airbrake, but is an open source solution. Errbit itself is a Rails webapp, and can centralize errors from multiple sources.

There is also a nice integration with [GitHub](http://github.com) (to create issues from errors) and [Campfire](http://campfirenow.com) (to get the errors directly inside the team chat room).